# how to show all decimal digits on php number_format

Tags: php, format, currency, number-formatting, separator

I get some data like this

```
1000000.42342
25000000.320
3412.412341
```

how to show all the data like:

```
1.000.000,42342
25.000.000,320
3.412,412341
```

in this case i use number_format, but in second argument needs total number of decimal.
Big thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you want to format numbers in different formats?

Comment: That can cause wierd behaviour sinds number format rounds numbers off

Comment: What you might want is to set a high number for the decimal precision and just `rtrim()` all zeros off

Comment: also good practise is to set `ini_set('precision', 17);` explicitely when working with higher precision decimal values

Comment: cause of different currency format. and if show with 2 decimal of number_format its maybe saved with new number where thats new number is rounded from original value.

Comment: same goes, use a super high value for the precision and rtrim all zeros off

Comment: i mean, how to display the entire decimal digit?

Comment: pls read my comment.